# Trouble creating LSTM model for multivariate forecasting

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, tensorflow2.0, forecasting

**The Data**: [Weather Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/muthuj7/weather-dataset)

The data provided is in hours.
[image]

As of now I only selected three parameters in the data frame.

*Input:*

```
df.info()
```

*Output:*

```
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    DatetimeIndex: 78888 entries, 2006-01-01 00:00:00 to 2014-12-31 23:00:00
    Freq: H
    Data columns (total 3 columns):
     #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype  
    ---  ------           --------------  -----  
     0   Temperature (C)  78888 non-null  float64
     1   Humidity         78888 non-null  float64
     2   Visibility (km)  78888 non-null  float64
    dtypes: float64(3)
    memory usage: 2.4 MB
```

One of the parameter's graph is as follows.

```
    df['Temperature (C)'].plot(figsize=(30,8))
```

[image: Temp in hrs]

First I thought of changing the Dataframe from *hourly data* to *monthly data* so it will be easier to train.

```
    df = df.resample('MS').mean()
```

Like this,

[image: Monthly dataframe]

And the variation of temperature in months is,

```
df['Temperature (C)'].plot(figsize=(30,8))
```

[image: temp in months]

#### Test & train:

```
    rows_per_month=1
    test_months = 18 #number of months we want to predict in the future.
    
    test_indices = test_months*rows_per_month
    test_indices
    
    # train and test split:
    train = df_final.iloc[:-test_indices]
    
    # Choose the variable/parameter you want to predict
    test = df_final.iloc[-test_indices:]
```

I scaled the data using `MinMaxScaler` from *sci-kit learn*

#### Generator Parameters:

```
    length =  12*rows_per_month #Length of output sequences (in number of timesteps)
    batch_size = 1 #Number of timeseries sample in batch
    generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train,scaled_train,length=length,batch_size=batch_size)
```

## Model for `df`(in months):

```
    # define model
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, input_shape=(length,scaled_train.shape[1]),return_sequences=True))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50))
    
    
    #NOTE: Do not specify the activation function for LSTM layers, this is because it will not run on GPU.
    model.add(Dense(scaled_train.shape[1]))
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

The model was trained for 24 epochs and did fairly well on predicting the three parameters as follows.

[image: Loss for month model]

## Prediction from model (when `df` is monthly):

[image: Prediction of monthly model]
This is a fairly decent prediction.

> The problem is when I increase the density of the data and make it
> to *daily* instead of *monthly*.

I used the original data and did the following:

```
    df = df.resample('D').mean()
```

The variation of temperature in days:

```
    df['Temperature (C)'].plot(figsize=(30,8))
```

[image: temp in days]

#### Test & train:

The only thing changed in here is `rows_per_month = 30`, rest everything is the same.

#### Generator Parameters:

Also the same as above.

## Model for `df`(in days):

**The same Model** (as I used when `df` was in months)

```
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, input_shape=(length,scaled_train.shape[1]),return_sequences=True))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50))
    # model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50)) #add this layer if df is in 'days'
    
    #NOTE: Do not specify the activation function for LSTM layers, this is because it will not run on GPU.
    model.add(Dense(scaled_train.shape[1]))
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

The model was trained for 24 epochs and the model did not predict properly.

### losses:

[image: Daily model loss]

## Prediction from model (when `df` is daily)

[image: prediction of daily model]

I tried adding one more layer of **50 LSTM** units.

```
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, input_shape=(length,scaled_train.shape[1]),return_sequences=True))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50)) #add this layer if df is in 'days'
    
    #NOTE: Do not specify the activation function for LSTM layers, this is because it will not run on GPU.
    model.add(Dense(scaled_train.shape[1]))
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

but the results were similar.

I also tried to train the model for more epochs (~ 100) but didn't get results.

I think I'm missing a key point, the periodicity of the data remains the same only the density of the points change, why is this affecting the accuracy of the model?

- How can I achieve a decent accuracy from the model which predicts daily parameters? and for hourly data as well?

Comment: Fundamentally, your question is about modeling, and not programming per se, so I suggest you to ask in https://stats.stackexchange.com/

In any case, time series forecasting is expected to be very sensible to the time resolution you pick, especially with recurrent nnets. You could leverage the monthly models in the daily ones with multi-resolution time-series analysis.